# iOS 8 Swift: Cannot unhide/hide UIView on button click

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

This is driving me crazy. I am trying to un-hide a hidden UIView on button click but its not working. Here is the code

```
import UIKit
class DownloadViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var activityView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.activityView.hidden = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func downloadAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.activityView.hidden = false
    }    
}
```

Please help me. This is driving me nuts, that its not doing such a simple thing.

Comment: It's working for me. Does your downloadAction get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your outlet is connected to the correct button in Interface Builder, try connecting it again by ctrl-dragging from the button in IB to the @IBOutlet code.

Answer (score 1):

This code works, are you getting an error or does the button not do anything?

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

import UIKit
class DownloadViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var activityView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.activityView.isHidden = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func downloadAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.activityView.isHidden = false
}
```

}